# ¿Es válida la palabra "realizador" para una persona que realiza una acción y no crea algo material?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Según [Realizador RAE](https://dle.rae.es/realizador)

Realizador es

> 1. m. y f. Persona que realiza o lleva a ejecución una obra.
> 2. m. y f. En el cine y la televisión, responsable de la ejecución de una película o programa.
> 3. m. y f. Técnico que va seleccionando una imagen de entre las diversas obtenidas por cámaras situadas en diferentes lugares.

A primera vista pareciera que se trata de crear algo material o que tenga algo material

Y según [Obra - RAE](https://www.google.com/search?q=obra%20significado&ei=T8jOYt3cM6iq1sQPocinSA&ved=0ahUKEwidwJGA_PX4AhUolZUCHSHkCQkQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=obra%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEIAEEEYQ-QEyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyCAgAEB4QDxAWMggIABAeEA8QFjoHCAAQRxCwAzoJCAAQsAMQChBDOg0ILhDHARDRAxCwAxBDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQxwEQ0QM6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOggILhCxAxCDAToHCC4Q1AIQQzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6CAgAELEDEIMBOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCvAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQrwEQ1AI6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOggIABCABBCxAzoHCAAQgAQQCkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFC_A1jeEmCoFGgDcAF4AIABsgGIAbIOkgEENi4xMJgBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)

> 1. f. Cosa hecha o producida por un agente.
> 2. f. Cualquier producto intelectual en ciencias, letras o artes, y con particularidad el que es de alguna importancia.
> 3. f. Tratándose de libros, volumen o volúmenes que contienen un trabajo literario completo.
> 4. f. Edificio en construcción. En este lugar hay muchas obras.
> 5. f. Lugar donde se está construyendo algo, o arreglando el pavimento.
> 6. f. Trabajo de albañilería que se hace en una casa. Tenemos obra en casa.
> 7. f. Medio, virtud o poder. Por obra del Espíritu Santo.
> 8. f. Trabajo que cuesta, o tiempo que requiere, la ejecución de algo. Esta pieza tiene mucha obra.
> 9. f. Labor que tiene que hacer un artesano.
> 10. f. Acción moral, y principalmente la que se encamina al provecho del alma, o la que le hace daño. U. m. en pl.
> 11. f. Cantidad que se satisface al erario o fábrica de una parroquia, colegiata, catedral, etc.
> 12. f. Ingen. Parte estrecha y prismática de un horno alto situada inmediatamente encima del crisol.

¿Aquí ya no me queda tan claro. Puede "cosa hecha o producida por agente" aplicarse a cualquier acción?

Otro de los significados es "medio, virtud o poder" . Entonces, "persona que realiza una obra" podría ser "persona que realiza un poder". Realizar un poder me suena mucho a realizar una acción.

¿Es válida la palabra realizador para una persona que realiza una acción y no crea algo material?

Comment: Por **un agente** es muy diferente a por **gente**. Algo realizado por un agente no tiene por qué ser gente, referido a personas. Quizás debas revisar la pregunta para que se entienda la consulta.

Comment: @Danielillo corregido, pero la pregunta sigue en pie. Por ejemplo, otros de los significados es "medio, virtud o poder" . Entonces, "persona que realiza una obra" podría ser "persona que realiza un poder". Realizar un poder me suena mucho a realizar una acción

Comment: Habría que seguir avanzando por el diccionario. Qué significa "cosa". ¿Puede una "acción" ser una "cosa"?

Comment: @rodrigo es otra duda que tengo pero podría ser, porque cosa hace referencia a algo inmaterial también, no sé si a cualquier algo inmaterial, como una acción

Comment: Todo esto viene de que quiero evitar usar la palabra "perpetrador" para alguien que está puesto en duda si cometió un delito o no con determinada acción. Si no cometió un delito, se podría usar la palabra realizador?

Answer (score 2):

Solo puedo dar ejemplos en base a lo cotidiano del idioma y las búsquedas en Google.

Por ejemplo, dentro de lo inmaterial como cosa a realizar está un "gesto" o una "mueca", pero no encontré ninguna acepción que exprese:

- El realizador de ese gesto
- La realizadora de esa mueca

Sin embargo, en jerga periodística sí que se utiliza el término realizar en gestas deportivas:

> Alvaro Visairas Gimenez ha mencionado que el paracaidismo es una actividad que inspira respeto y admiración para aquellos que lo practican debido a las emociones fuerte y únicas que provoca en **el realizador del salto**

<sub>*Fuente [eltiempo-ecuador.com](https://eltiempo-ecuador.com/novedades/el-paracaidista-alvaro-visairas-gimenez-habla-sobre-la-practica-de-este-deporte/)*</sub>

> Hoy, Óliver Torres es el segundo jugador más joven en debutar en la Liga de Campeones y **el realizador del gol** más rápido de la historia del Atlético.

<sub>*Fuente [elmundo.es](https://www.elmundo.es/deportes/2013/10/28/526e2427684341bf558b45bc.html)*</sub>

Pero si haces búsquedas verás que no es algo muy habitual y como está descrito anteriormente se reduce a terminología periodística.

---

Alternativas a *realizador* en hechos no necesariamente materiales, podrían ser **ejecutor**, **provocador**, **causante**, **promotor**.

Ejemplos:

- El provocador del desencuentro
- La ejecutora del desenlace
- El promotor de la acción
- La causante del disgusto

En el campo judicial la expresión no directamente acusatoria más utilizada es **artífice** :

> Pablo Almansa es el artífice del delito, el ladrón que hurta miradas gracias a su maestría en la fotografía de desnudo.

<sub>*Fuente [elmundo.es](https://www.elmundo.es/albumes/2008/11/14/disparos_desnudo_almansa/index.html)*</sub>

Comment: Mucho más común que "realizador del gol" es "autor del gol".

Answer (score -1):

¿Es válida la palabra "realizador" para una persona que realiza una acción y no crea algo material?

Entiendo que es una cuestión ciertamente ambivalente. Un realizador puede hacer una acción y no crea algo material. El "Realizador" puede llevar simples acciones que no son ejecutadas por él, puede llevar mensajes de otros, y si se presta también puede ser la persona que las active y ejecute. Depende cual haya sido el cometido que le han asignado.

---

**Diccionario índice de jurisprudencia penal 1983-1988**. Tomo II. 4175 A tenor del art. 14 del CP son tres fundamentalmente las vías para que se pueda considerar a una persona autora de un delito. La participación directa en la ejecución del mismo; la inducción del mismo al que se equipara a efectos penales la fuerza física ejercida sobre el **realizador** material para que se cometa y la cooperación necesaria, esto es aportar la ejecución del hecho..

https://books.google.es/books?id=vRFMwwYvr90C&pg=PA530&lpg=PA530&dq=A+tenor+del+art.+14+del+C.P.+son+tres+fundamentalmente+las+vias+para+que+se+pueda+considerar+a+una+persona+autora+de+un+delito&source=bl&ots=cF-xsGAu5f&sig=ACfU3U0KNJG0Q4I8t1fmmRPCFlCzfggUrA&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG5L-xy_v4AhUHQfEDHTy4B_sQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=A%20tenor%20del%20art.%2014%20del%20C.P.%20son%20tres%20fundamentalmente%20las%20vias%20para%20que%20se%20pueda%20considerar%20a%20una%20persona%20autora%20de%20un%20delito&f=false

---

Depende del contexto.

La aparición del término "Realizador" referido a la producción para el cine o la televisión, como responsable de la ejecución de una película o programa, ha provocado que las distintas acepciones anteriores se difuminen, siendo ésta, la referida a los medios, la que prevalezca sobre otras. Su terminología comenzó a recogerse de forma oficial en el Real Decreto Legislativo 1/1996 de 12 de Abril, texto refundido BOE 22/4/1996. Título VI Obras Cinematográficas y demás obras audiovisuales: Art. 87 Autores.

1.-  El Director-Realizador.

2.- Los autores del argumento....

---

Por otra parte se considera sinónimo de Realizador los siguientes;

- Director
- Autor
- Agente
- Artífice
- Ejecutor

---

Independientemente de las ideas anteriores, influencias por el ámbito técnico, el "**Realizador**" es simplemente el que se ocupa o puede llevar a cabo distintas conductas, actuaciones o trabajos tanto por separado como de forma conjunta. Estos "realizadores" puede ser  pintores, sastres, médicos...y dependerá de como el interlocutor se dirige a ellos;

No todos necesariamente crearán algo considerado estrictamente material.

- Mi realizador del gabán de la fábula de Pelión, no ha terminado. (Se refiere a su sastre, que aún no ha terminado una determinada prenda).
- Además de realizador, analiza los problemas que ocasionan este tipo de pinturas (se refiere al pintor o realizador de las pinturas).
- Es un gran realizador de noticieros, (Curiosamente se refiere a un presentador de noticias).
- Realizador de la lucha contra dicha enfermedad (paludismo). (Se refiere a un doctor que lleva y lidera la lucha contra la enfermedad del paludismo).
- Requieren en el Realizador condiciones referenciales...(Realizador, como persona involucrada a nivel lexicográfico)
- a. pecoris, conductor del ganado, actor, ejecutor, realizador. Realizador como el que activa, guía, ejecutor, conductor del ganado.
- annalium c. Redacción de anales. Libri c., Composición de un libro, realización, preparación extenuación debilitamiento.

---

El realizador puede llevar a cabo cualquier cosa tanto material como inmaterial, pues el mismo término "cosa" que puede designar por un lado a todo aquello que existe o tiene entidad ya sea material, real y concreto, y por otro lado, aquellas que son inmateriales, imaginarias, o abstractas.

---

Respecto a los comentarios

*quiero evitar usar la palabra "perpetrador" para alguien que está puesto en duda si cometió un delito o no con determinada acción. Si no cometió un delito, ¿se podría usar la palabra realizadar?*

Lo lógico para esos casos es utilizar el término "presunto", "presunto inocente", "presunto culpable", "presunto autor del delito"...como autor material, ejecutor, autor mediato (interponiendo a otras personas), utilizando participes, cómplices

"a veces los hechos que son ajenos a la voluntad de los realizadores del ilícito". "Realizadores como presuntos culpables en calidad de autor, en proceso por determinar la autoría de los diferentes delitos a los que se enfrentan los presuntos acusados..."

Comment: Quizás sea conveniente que todas las citas que mencionas, en esta respuesta son siete, vengan acompañadas del enlace o la cita de donde han sido extractadas. Tal como están dispuestas actualmente pueden ser siete frases inventadas que no solo no aportan nada a la pregunta sino que incluso confunden al sentido de lo expuesto.

Comment: Educación física: Educación Secundaria Obligatoria. Escrito por Fernando Ureña Villanueva. Tipos de Profesor. 1) El profesor como consumidor autónomo. 2) El profesor como consumidor-realizador. El profesor realizador-autónomo. Planifica y diseña materias para cursos completos. (1991). pag. 11

Comment: Satisfacciones imaginarias. Del lado de los cautivos Escrito por Francisco Javier Pérez Como siguiendo la fascinación " flaubertiana " por este género de escritura salvadora, Sebald, aunque nunca actuó como realizador diccionario-lógico , va a desplegar la presencia encantadora del diccionario en muchos momentos de su narrativa.

Comment: El gran libro de los nombres en 5 idiomas Escrito por Laura Tuan. ...inflexible, de pocas palabras pero optimó y ágil realizador de proyectos. Melancolía, sensibilidad, religiosidad, frialdad y desapego en el amor. Dinámico y realizador, Fabricio se muestra práctico también en el amor. Sobre los nombres de personas.

Comment: Las familias de palabras. Relaciones entre morfología, semántica Escrito por Héctor Hernández Arocha. Si consideramos este pacto desde el punto de vista del realizador de la acción, entonces entenderemos la i del DRAR..

Comment: Diccionario índice de jurisprudencia penal 1983-1988. Tomo II. 4175 A tenor  del art. 14 del CP son tres fundamentalmente las vías para que se pueda considerar a una persona autora de un delito. La participación directa en la ejecución del mismo; la inducción del mismo al que se equipara a efectos penales la fuerza física ejercida sobre el realizador material para que se cometa y la cooperación necesaria, esto es aportar la ejecución del hecho...

Comment: Más bien me refería a añadirlos en la respuesta, con enlaces si son citas de internet. En respuestas a mi comentario no creo sean de gran ayuda.